# What are the symmetries of the Schrödinger functional?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, klein-gordon-equation

Given the definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_functional).
What are the symmetries of:

$$\mathcal{S}[\phi_2,t_2;\phi_1,t_1]=\langle\,\phi_2\,|e^{-iH(t_2-t_1)/\hbar}|\,\phi_1\,\rangle.$$

which is the amplitude to go from the field configuration $
\phi_1$ at time $t_1$ to $
\phi_2$ at $t_2$ for a scalar Klein Gordon field.

Some I know. It must be invariant under translations in time:

$$\mathcal{S}[\phi_2,t_2;\phi_1,t_1]= \mathcal{S}[\phi_2,t_2+t';\phi_1,t_1+t']$$

(Infinitessimal) translations in space:

$$\mathcal{S}[\phi_2,t_2;\phi_1,t_1] = \mathcal{S}[\phi_2+a.\nabla
\phi_2,t_2;\phi_1+a.\nabla
\phi_1,t_1]$$
And also general Lorenz transformations.

Since if we translate or rotate both the input and output fields the amplitude should remain the same.

Does it have any other symmetries?

For example is it invariant under a general addition of a scalar field:

$$\mathcal{S}[\phi_2,t_2;\phi_1,t_1] = \mathcal{S}[\phi_2+\phi_3
,t_2;\phi_1+
\phi_3,t_1] ? $$

and if not. Why not? (Since the solution of the Klein Gordon equation is linear?)